# How to show employee name and number of projects being worked on only for employees working on multiple projects?

Tags: sql, count, project

Currently I have a query which will show employee names who are working on multiple projects along with the projects they are currently working on. However I don't know how to modify this to just show each employee once along with the count of number of projects they are working on.

```
select e.lname, w.pno
from employee e inner join works_on w on e.ssn = w.essn
where e.ssn in (select essn from works_on GROUP BY essn HAVING COUNT(essn) > 1);
```

If y'all could provide a quick explanation of why/how it works please let me know!

Thank you very much in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
select e.lname, count(*) cnt_projects
from employee e 
inner join works_on w on e.ssn = w.essn
group by e.ssn, e.lname
having count(*) > 1
```